# How do I redirect an authorized user to their respective dashboard view using Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am having a problem in redirecting authorized user to their respective dashboard view. I am using php/laravel.

it mostly says that my DashboardController class is not found. what should I do with this?

this is my AuthManager controller.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session as FacadesSession;

class AuthManager extends Controller
{
    function login(){
        if(Auth::check()){
            return redirect(route('dashboard'));
        }
        return view('login');
    }

    function registration(){
        if(Auth::check()){
            return redirect(route('home'));
        }
        return view('registration');
    }

    function loginPost(Request $request){
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        $credentials = $request->only('email','password');
        if(Auth::attempt($credentials)){
            return redirect()->intended(route('dashboard'));
        }
        return redirect(route('login'))->with("error", "Login details are Incorrect");
    }

    function registrationPost(Request $request){
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        $data['name'] = $request->name;
        $data['email'] = $request->email;
        $data['password'] = Hash::make($request->password);
        $user = User ::create($data);
        if(!$user){
            return redirect(route('registration'))->with("error", "Registration Details are Incorrect");
        }
        return redirect(route('login'));
    }

    function logout(){
        FacadesSession::flush();
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect(route('login'));
    }
}
```

my dashboard controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('dashboard');
    }
}
```

my web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthManager;
use \App\Http\Controllers\ForgotPasswordManager;
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
| be assigned to the "web" middleware group. Make something great!
|
*/


Route::get('/', [AuthManager::class, 'login'])->name('login');
Route::post('/login', [AuthManager::class, 'loginPost'])->name('login.post');
Route::get('/registration', [AuthManager::class, 'registration'])->name('registration');
Route::post('/registration', [AuthManager::class, 'registrationPost'])->name('registration.post');
Route::get('/logout', [AuthManager::class, 'logout'])->name('logout');
Route::get("/forgot-password",[ForgotPasswordManager::class, "forgotPassword"])->name("forgot.password");
Route::post("/forgot-password",[ForgotPasswordManager::class, "forgotPasswordPost"])->name("forgot.password.post");
Route::get("/reset-password/{token}", [ForgotPasswordManager::class, "resetPassword"])->name("reset.password");
Route::post("/reset-password",[ForgotPasswordManager::class, "resetPasswordPost"])->name("reset.password.post");
Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
```

I need it to redirect to the dashboard view.

Answer (score 0):

It is saying **DashboardController class is not found** because it cannot find your controller without namespace.

Try to change your route to

```
Route::get('/dashboard', 'App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
```

But it is better to use routes like this:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController;

Route::get('/dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'index')->name('dashboard');
```